# Changing the value of the checkboxes via jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a few checkboxes in my form and I need to change their value when the checkbox is checked.

For example this is one of the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="drink" value=""/>
```

I know  `.val()` can change it but I wasn't able to do this with `if` statement.

I appreciate your answer in advance.

Comment: what check box being checked changes which other check box? your question lacks details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// attach an onchange handler to all checkboxes on the page
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {

    // or if($(this).prop("checked")) {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(this).val("value for checked");
    } else {
        $(this).val("value for unchecked");
    }
});
```

- The `onchange` event is the one you should be interested when it comes to checkboxes, as it fires whenever you change the checked state of it.
- The `checked` property determines whether or not the checkbox has been checked.
- The `.val()` method allows you to conveniently read/write element values.

Comment: Thank you Karim, your answer saved me.

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeking is actually very meaningless. See, when a form is submitted, only the **checked** checkboxes actually send values, so it makes no sense to change the value especially for the unchecked checkbox.

---

## Better Solution

You should instead give it the "checked" value, and keep it that way, that will cause it to submit correctly even without changing the values.

Comment: I didn't explain my purpose, I only asked the part that I was missing to finish my project. The other answers solved my problem.thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a click event listener on the checkbox:

```
$('input[name="drink"]').click(function() { // when click on it
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {          // if the checkbox is checked
       $(this).val("value #1");             // change the value
    } else {                                // otherwise if is unchecked
       $(this).val("value #2");             // change the value
    }
});
```

Comment: Better attach a listener to the `change` event. The state of checkboxes can be changed with the keyboard as well, but your code would not capture that.